# Install gem/mongify in openSUSE

Tags: rubygems, mongify

I am planning to migrate mysql data to mongoDB and decided to use mongify. I have both mysql and mongoDB are running in openSUSE 12.x . In order to install mongify in openSUSE, I need rubygems installed and running. How do I install rubygems in openSUSE and use gem install?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Try 
http://smithfarm-thebrain.blogspot.ca/2014/04/how-to-install-ruby-gems-in-opensuse.html

Looks like you have to install Ruby Developers package using zypper

> zypper in ruby-devel

Comment: It's 2020 and this enabled me to install gems in Tumbleweed.